# Parse Server Cloud Code Logging

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, dashboard, parse-server

I have successfully set up my own Parse Server on AWS. I have not been able to implement logging that is visible in the dashboard, nor have I been able to locate log files on the server itself that pertain to cloud code. (there are console.log statements throughout the functions.)

I have found a few references, but nothing explicit as how to implement... (only experience with Node.js is to set up parse server)

This is a screenshot taken from https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server.
The "usage" described for the environment variable does not match the other environment variables such as appId or masterKey in the AWS configuration section. (the descriptor is in a separate column than the value, and there is no equal sign). If this goes in a file, which one? Is the path to file absolute or relative?
[image: parse server logging]

I also have "var logger=..." in require section & loggerAdapter in the "var=api.." section as seen in the link below. And yet, I cannot get logging to work. 
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/1904

Any ideas or references to help clarify this?

Please no links back to the Parse Server main page on Github or blogs that copy the same information with no additional insight.

Comment: Ok, so I have figured out that logs (console.log(), etc) are showing in /var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log   Still can't figure out how to get to show in the dashboard. While this is less important as I can now see the log files, would still know how to do it.

Comment: Did you use elastic beankstalk CLI to upload your parse-server-example project?

Comment: @Santhosh, yes. I did use EB CLI to upload parse-server-example.

Comment: In that case you can use `eb logs` to get the latest logs.

Comment: Thank you for this information. It appears this log file is the same one that is available from the EB dashboard that gives the last 100 lines of grouped log files. Within it is where I found the path for the logs that "should" show up in cloud code. (/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log). I am now trying to figure out how to get this file to show in the parse-server dashboard.